# How to use awkward alt keys that have the same number twice?

Tags: alt

How do I use alt keys that have the same number twice - e.g. to do `Ĺ`, you have to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0313 - how?
B.T.W. - I got the symbol from the following website: [mvdmoosdijk](http://www.mvdmoosdijk.nl/Misc/Altcodes/Alt-codes_for_characters.htm).

Comment: You only hold alt the whole time. This code is "Hold Alt (entire time) press 0, let got of 0. Press 3, let go of 3. Press 1, let go of 1. Press 3, let go of 3. Let go of alt. Character appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to hold all of the numbers, just press and hold 'Alt' and then type in 0313 as if you were typing in that number.